# Check if record subscription already exists in CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift3, cloudkit

I couldn't find a proper and right way to check if a CKRecord subscription already exists, and if it doesn't then subscribe to it to get push notifications.

I've implemented the subscription itself and it's responding, but every time I enter the proper View Controller I'm always trying to subscribe again and the server replies with an error if that subscription already exists - My question is: Is there any way to check first if the subscription exists instead of trying to create it and wait for the server response?

Here's how I'm subscribing to a record:

```
    // Create the predicate
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recordId = %@", RECORD_ID)

// Create a subscription specifying the record type, predicate and notification options
let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Tabs", predicate: predicate, options: [.firesOnRecordUpdate, .firesOnRecordCreation])

// Create a CloudKit notification object
let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = "Updates have been made"
notificationInfo.shouldBadge = true

// Set the subscriptor's notification object to the new CloudKit notification object
subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

// Save the subscription to the database
let publicDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
publicDatabase.save(subscription) { (subs, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Failed to save subscription:", err)
        return
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler` to query all existing subs, then you can check `subscriptionID` property on each sub returned in the completion handler. The objective-c version looks like:

```
    [publicDatabase fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<CKSubscription *> * _Nullable subscriptions, NSError * _Nullable error)
    {
        NSMutableArray *subIDs = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (CKSubscription *sub in subscriptions)
        {
            if ([sub.subscriptionID isEqualToString:@"whatever"];
            {
                  //do some stuff
            }
        }
    }];
```

However, you mention re-entering a view controller and re-running this check. Not that this check issues a request to the server each time and will thus count against your transaction and transfer quotas. I recommend instead that you run this check once on app startup, and then save the state of each sub in class variables so you don't have to keep re-querying the server repeatedly with unnecessary calls.